# Call to a member function addDays() on string on Laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I have a store function. In the store function, I want to create a date format using carbon. You can see this code here:

```
public function store_cuti(Request $request)
{
    $end = $request->tgl_mulai->addDays(3);

    $users = new Data_cuti;
    $users->user_id                 = $request->user_id ; // users_id
    $users->nama_surat        = $request->nama_surat ; 
    $users->tgl_surat              = $request->tgl_surat ;
    $users->durasi_cuti          = $request->durasi_cuti ; // this input is number integer like 1,2,3
    $users->tgl_mulai             = $request->tgl_mulai ; // this input is Date formate 
    $users->tgl_selesai           = $end; // it will going to date format too
    $users->status                  = $request->status ;

}
```

I did this, but `$end` has the error `Call to a member function addDays() on string`.

I added this on my Models:

```
  protected $dates = ['tgl_mulai'];
```

but it did not have an effect. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`tgl_mulai` property of the Model would be cast as Date but NOT `tgl_mulai` property of `$request`, which is string, hence you are getting the above error.

You would need to cast the string into a carbon instance to call functions of carbon on it.

```
$end = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->tgl_mulai)->addDays(3);
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Carbon to convert string into a date, In your case you can try as below

```
 $end = Carbon::parse($request->tgl_mulai)->addDays(3);
```

Then you can also format the date as you expect

```
$end->format('Y-m-d'); //returns string
```

for more information you may look at [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

`$request->tgl_mulai` is a string and the is trying to say that you can't use addDays() method on it. This method can only be used on a Carbon object. The solution is simple, just create a Carbon instance from `$request->tgl_mulai` and then add 3 days.

`$end = new Carbon($request->tgl_mulai)->addDays(3);`

Then convert your Carbon date to a string like this.

`$users->tgl_selesai = $end->toDateString(); // 1975-12-25`

More formats can be found on official Carbon documentation right here - https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use php date to add days.

```
$end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->tgl_mulai. ' + 3 days'));
```